# Build and Install Qt-4.7.3 ERROR on CentOS 5.6 x64

Tags: qt, centos, vmware

I am having an error when trying to install the Qt-4.7.3 libraries on CentOS 5.6. The error I am getting is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcg
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [../../../bin/moc] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chlong/Libraries/qt-4.7.3/src/tools/moc'
gmake: *** [sub-moc-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

My CentOS is running off of VMWare 3.1.3. I have tried re-downlading and re-installing Qt as well as re-installing VMWare and re-installing CentOS, but to no avail.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never heard of that `-ltcg` library. What configuration options are you choosing?

Answer (score 0):

A work around is to compile with '-no-ltcg'

Alternatively, the EPEL repository has qt give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

try running the command gmake install as a root user

otherwise you may avoid installing lctg by providing configuration flag --no ltcg,if you dont need ltcg.........